# Can I use extern for macros?

Tags: c, macros, extern

I know that functions are tagged `extern` in C by default and it is also possible to use an `extern` variable in C (if it is initialized in some other file or if I write `extern int foo = 1;`). But can I use `extern` for a C macro because they behave like functions?

Comment: You can't legitimately write `extern int foo = 1;`.  You can write either `int foo = 1;` or `extern int foo;` but you can't say 'defined somewhere else' (`extern`) and give an initializer too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless something radically changed in C99, preprocessor macros don't have storage classes.  You can't declare them without simultaneously defining them.  They aren't even treated by the compiler in the same way that other identifiers are treated -- they're a purely textual translation that (at least conceptually) happens even before the compiler attempts any kind of name lookup.

Comment: Nothing changed in C99 or C2011 related to macros having storage classes.